# How to define TYPES with Cassandra Consistencies?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cql3

I have the following:

```
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var clientCass = new cassandra.Client({
    contactPoints: ['localhost'],
    keyspace: 'localhost'
});
```

Towards the bottom of the code, I'm doing this:

```
//Now add a row or Check to see if the session already exists
        var query = "INSERT INTO localhost.shirosessions     (id,expired,last_access_ts,start_ts) \n\
                VALUES ('" + theSession.sessionid + "',false,'" 
                + component.getTimeStampA() + "','" + component.getTimeStampA() + "') IF NOT EXISTS";


        //var params = [];
        var consistency = client.cql.types.consistencies.quorum;
        //client.executeAsPrepared(query, params, consistency, function (err) {
        clientCass.execute(query, consistency, function (err) {
            if (err)
                console.log('Something when wrong and the row was not Inserted', err);
            else {
                console.log('Inserted on the cluster! Yay!');
            }
        });
```

BUT, the error I'm getting is this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'types' of undefined
```

I don't understand? Where is TYPES defined? How?

I'm new to Cassandra and yet I've been using MSSQL Server since the late 90s and have a clear understanding of SQL.

Thanks if you can help.

Also, is putting "IF EXISTS" the only way to ensure a UNIQUE record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using the node.js driver.  Is this correct?

Try using:

```
var consistency = cassandra.types.consistencies.quorum;
```

> I'm new to Cassandra and yet I've been using MSSQL Server since the late 90s and have a clear understanding of SQL.

Yep, I was the same way.  The best advice I can offer is to not let that influence your understanding of Cassandra at all.  There are *several* CQL keywords taken from SQL that do not behave *at all* like their relational counterparts.  It's important to read the docs and assume nothing.

> Also, is putting "IF EXISTS" the only way to ensure a UNIQUE record?

No, all PRIMARY KEYs in Cassandra are unique.  What you need to understand, is that Cassandra treats all INSERTs and UPDATEs **exactly the same**.  They are colloquially known as "UPSERTs."

By executing an UPSERT, you are telling Cassandra to take your column values and store them for the given keys.  If a row already exists for those keys, then the existing column values will be overwritten with the new column values.  When you use an `IF [NOT] EXISTS` you are telling Cassandra not to bother with the UPSERT if the key values are already present.